# Как правильно применить аргумент привязки this

Tags: javascript

```
var deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.video-box span');
for (var i = deleteBtn.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    deleteBtn[i].addEventListener('click', deleteVideo);
}

function deleteVideo() {
    var videoBox = document.querySelectorAll('.video-box');
    for (var i = videoBox.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        videoBox[i].remove();
    }
}
```

Этот кусок кода удаляет все элементы VideoBox, а хотелось бы чтобы удалял только конкретный в котором собственно и нажимаешь на deleteBtn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменить в цикле `var на  let`

```js
var deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.video-box span');

var videoBox = document.querySelectorAll('.video-box');

for (let i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; i++) {

  deleteBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    videoBox[i].remove();

  });
}
```

```html
<div class="video-box">video-box1 <span>span</span></div>
<div class="video-box">video-box2 <span>span</span></div>
<div class="video-box">video-box3 <span>span</span></div>
<div class="video-box">video-box4 <span>span</span></div>
<div class="video-box">video-box5 <span>span</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для поиска ближайшего родителя используем [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

В `this` попадает элемент, который вызвал событие.

```
var deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.video-box span');
for (var i = deleteBtn.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    deleteBtn[i].addEventListener('click', deleteVideo);
}

function deleteVideo() {
    this.closest('.video-box').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Комментарий выше абсолютно верен, но для большей элегантности можно перебирать в данном случае через `forEach` вместо `for`, где также можно обратиться к конкретному элементу.

```
var deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.video-box span');

deleteBtn.forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    btn.closest('.video-box').remove();
  });
});
```